# Do 250 buttons slow the application in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'm building a BattleShip game for WP7 that has board with 250 cells. I need to make each cell clickable, so I thought to put in each cell a button and handle each click as I need.

My question is: do 250 buttons slow the phone? If it does, so what are the alternatives?

Comment: How are you going to fit 250 cells on a 480x800 pixels screen without confusing my stubby fingers?

Comment: @Emo I'll let you borrow the stylus from my Nintendo DS

Comment: @ColinE - :) thanks. On a 15x15 grid you'd have 32 pixels per button. That is very tiny.

Comment: @Emo I'll lend you my glasses as well then :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hell yes. 250 UI controls are complete utter madness. The alternative, and correct solution, is to use XNA instead, and developing your game as a real game, and not as a bunch of UI controls.

Comment: I disagree, I would not say XNA is necessarily the correct solution for a Battleship game. You could certainly create one in a much more lightweight way using Silverlight.

Comment: I'm most certain that it'll be more lightweight in XNA than Silverlight, even with the most simple user controls. Neither WPF or Silverlight on the desktop cope very well with large amount of controls. So on a mobile phone, it'll be even worse.

Comment: Sure - my point is, he doesn't need controls? does he need a Click event or just mouse events? does he need command binding? visual states? templating? if not, a simple Rectangle, or WriteableBitmap will do.

Comment: Mouse positions and a bitmap could work out. But then you're practically re-doing what XNA is so good at.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 250 buttons will make your application quite slow. Silverlight constructs a visual tree to represent your UI. Each button contains a template which generates various broders, rectangles etc ... for representing visual states.

A couple of alternatives are:

1. Use a more lightweight visual elements, for example `Rectangle`. These do not have a `Click` event, so you can handle `MouseLeftButtonUp` instead.
2. Probably the most lightweight approach is not to have an element for each cell at all. Simply handle mouse interactions on a parent element, then determine the grid cell from the click location. The `MouseEventArgs` contain a `e.GetPosition()` method that allows you to determine where the mouse click occurred.

Comment: By 2nd approach you mean to use some kind of image of grid and by clicking the image I calculate the cell?